# When sendKeys() is done by automated test the OK button still greyed out even if values are entred, is there a solution for that?

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation

I'm using testng framework, java and appium in order to automate tests for a site in a safari browser in Ipad simulator.

when sendKeys() is done, the "OK" button still greyed out even if values are entred, is there a solution for that?

Here an example when i go `sendKeys("GET");` button ok still greyed out, but when i tap it manual this problem doesn't exist.

[image]

Comment: Would ask you to provide info as suggested by Kudin in his answer. Also does trying `sendKeys("GET\n");` proceeds or not?

Comment: The problem was that i was sending an existing name so that it will be greyed out not accepting double.

Comment: and the behaviour details were always missing in the question, anyway I believe this shall be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i was sending an existing name so that it will be greyed out not accepting double.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to enter the text into the element by hand and then in DOM check whether the text of the element was modified or the value attribute of the element. If it's the value, then you should change that attribute via

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'Text')", element);
```

Although more info would be helpful, like DOM structure, etc.